# Calculate word embeddings using fasttext

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, fasttext

I am trying to calculate the word embeddings using fasttext for the following sentence.

```
a = 'We are pencil in the hands'
```

I dont have any pretrained model, so how do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table of trained embeddings.

You can download pre-trained embeddings from the [FastText website](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) and use the code they provide for loading the embeddings. You don't even need to install FastText for that:

```py
import io

def load_vectors(fname):
    fin = io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='ignore')
    n, d = map(int, fin.readline().split())
    data = {}
    for line in fin:
        tokens = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        data[tokens[0]] = map(float, tokens[1:])
    return data
```

Then you just pick-up the from the dictionary.

Alternatively, you can train fasttext yourself on your text data by following a [tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html). The reasonable minimum of a dataset to train the word embeddings on is hundreds of thousands of words.